# how to connect teradata using HP UFT

Tags: teradata, hp-uft

I am trying to do feasibility of Teradata SQL Assistant using UFT.

Please help me to start and understanding this, since i am new to DB Validation.

Also i checked in internet how to connect DB using UFT i Found below code

```
'Create ADODB connection object
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


'Create Recordsetobject
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


'Connect to DB using provider and server
objConnection.open "provider=sqloledb;Server=;User Id=; 
Password=;Database=;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

'Write the SQL Query
sqlQuery="Select * from emp"


'Execute the query
 objRecordSet.open sqlQuery, objConnection


'Display output
 value = objRecordSet.fields.item(0)               
 msgbox Value


objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
```

My team is connecting through Teradata.net not odbc connection, Will this code will work ? if not how to connect and retrieve data from teradata.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Abu.

Comment: sqloledb provider is the .net tunnel through odbc. For this you will still need to setup an ODBC connection and use Data Source instead of Server in the connect string.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try TD's native .net driver. Then you conn string would look like: connString = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=$servername;User ID=$username;Password=$password;Session Mode=ANSI;"

Comment: Tried this connString = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=$servername;User ID=$username;Password=$password;Session Mode=ANSI;" but i am getting error "Provider cannot be found" @access_granted

Comment: Well, you need to download the .NET driver from the TD site and install it, obviously.